# What is the fastest way to bulk load a large CSV file into MSSQL using Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

What is the fastest way to import data into MSSQL using Python with these requirements:

1. Large file (too big for memory, no row based inserts).
2. Minimal logging.
3. CSV file.
4. CSV file column may contain single and double quotes.
5. CSV file Column may contain line breaks.

Thanks.

Comment: CSV File may contain line breaks? Don't all csv files contain line breaks? What is special about these linebreaks? Are you using a different line delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

Call [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162802.aspx) in windows or [freebcp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/freebcp) for Linux from python code .